# How to get rid of an extra Windows Boot Manager entry in UEFI?

Tags: windows-10, uefi

My system firmware is seeing two Windows boot manager entries, on the same device.
It has only one EFI partition, and only one of the entries boots properly, how do I know where it is and how to delete it?
I don't want multiple Windows entries, even if they both boot.
I tried renaming one of the EFI files to no avail, but thinking about it, maybe the firmware doesn't care about file suffixes?
Here's a list of my .efi files in the partition:

```
./EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
./EFI/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi
./EFI/Boot/fbx64.efi
./EFI/Boot/mmx64.efi
./EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
./EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
./EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
./EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
./EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi
```

Comment: Are they both literally titled "Windows Boot Loader" (...or "Windows Boot **Manager**")?

Comment: Manager, you're right, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the boot entries are manually added during OS installation – not by simply placing a file in \EFI – so if you remove the file, the boot entry referencing it won't automatically disappear either.

(Although some firmwares do try to *specifically* auto-detect `bootmgfw.efi` as Windows Boot Manager, but typically only if an entry is missing – and this should result in exactly the same entry as Windows creates anyway.)

- If the entry is named "Windows Boot *Loader*", it's already not a standard Windows boot entry. The ones created by Windows (i.e. by bcdboot.exe) are labelled "Windows Boot **Manager**".
- From Windows, use `bcdedit /enum firmware` to show the UEFI boot entries (converted to the BCD format, but nevertheless representing firmware entries). The current one will be shown with `{bootmgr}` as the identifier, while all other entries will have full GUIDs.

  It should be possible to use `bcdedit /delete {THE_GUID}` to remove a firmware boot entry, or to change its label using `bcdedit /set {THE_GUID} description BAD` so that you could delete it later.
- From Linux, use `efibootmgr` to show the UEFI boot entries. (If you have an older version of efibootmgr, you'll need to add `-v` to show the path as well.) Compare each entry's shown partition GUID and file path with the GUIDs in `partx /dev/nvme0n1`, or use `efibootmgr -n XXXX` to temporarily select one specific entry for "next boot" (and reboot to test if it's the working one or not).

  Once you've determined which entry is bad, use `efibootmgr -b XXXX --delete-bootnum` to remove it.

Comment: Deleted it with efibootmgr but windows keeps creating it again, in bcdedit deleting it will stick?

Comment: I think that happens on at least some UEFI firmware when on the same drive and/or ESP, `EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi` is not the same file as `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`.

Comment: Turns out, my C (ntfs) drive had an EFI folder, renaming it solved the issue, found it using the partx scanning all partitions on my computer.

Comment: So it's probably not Windows but the firmware creating it whenever it detects that file. A bit annoying.

Comment: Doubt it, I don't think the firmware can read NTFS.

Comment: No, some of them actually can read NTFS. (I _think_ Gigabyte and newer Asus are such examples?) One way to find out is by booting into an EFI Shell (shellx64.efi) and poking around the drives it maps automatically.

Comment: UEFI firmware by AMI ("Aptio") does.